# 3D rotation in Python given two sets of vectors

Tags: python, scipy, graphics, 3d, quaternions

I have two set of vectors where the first is a rotated version of the second. I want to align them together and find the rotation matrix which satisfies it. The best way I found so far is `scipy.spatial.transform.Rotation.align_vectors`. By doing so, I get a better fit, but there is always some plane which the two are reflected about. I was told to use quotation, which may overcome this issue, but I am not sure.
Any ideas?